# Pulling all the form values from a posted array

Tags: php

I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="mypage.php" orderform="" name="" id="orderform">
<a id="add">+</a>
 <table width="533" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" id="ordertable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">Product Code (e.g 66203)</td>
      <td width="33%">mtrs sq Required (e.g 10)</td>
      <td width="33%">Preview Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode "><input type="text" id="prodcode[]" name="prodcode[]" class=" "></td>
      <td class="meterage"><input type="text" id="meterage[]" name="meterage[]"></td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode "><input type="text" id="prodcode[]" name="prodcode[]" class=" "></td>
      <td class="meterage"><input type="text" id="meterage[]" name="meterage[]"></td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to receive the post and print the associate product value with its meterage...as below ( this only seems to return the last result) any ideas?

```
    $number_of_products=count($_POST['prodcode']);
   for ( $i=0; $i<$number_of_products; $i++){
       $orderdetails = $_POST['prodcode'][$i]." has the meterage: ".$_POST['meterage'][$i]."<br/>";
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the content of $orderdetails each time the for loop is run.

Try something like this:

```
$number_of_products=count($_POST['prodcode']);
$orderdetails = "<h1>Order Details</h1>";
for ( $i=0; $i<$number_of_products; $i++){
       $orderdetails .= $_POST['prodcode'][$i]." has the meterage: ".$_POST['meterage'][$i]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it takes 1 more pair of eyes to catch things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try indexing the `prodcode[]` and `meterage[]` names on your input fields, i.e.:

```
<form method="post" action="mypage.php" orderform="" name="" id="orderform">
<a id="add">+</a>
 <table width="533" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" id="ordertable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">Product Code (e.g 66203)</td>
      <td width="33%">mtrs sq Required (e.g 10)</td>
      <td width="33%">Preview Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode "><input type="text" id="prodcode_0" name="prodcode[0]" class=" "></td>
      <td class="meterage"><input type="text" id="meterage_0" name="meterage[0]"></td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode "><input type="text" id="prodcode_1" name="prodcode[1]" class=" "></td>
      <td class="meterage"><input type="text" id="meterage_1" name="meterage[1]"></td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I needed to keep the array as it was but thank you for your input! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it because you overwrite it everytime
change
$orderdetails =
to 
$orderdetails .=